# Menu Navigation: Able to fade in but not sure how to fade out on close (Tailwind CSS & Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html, menu, css-animations, tailwind-css

I am currently experimenting with TailwindCSS transitions and Vanilla JS. Right now, I am able to fade in the menu navigation page when clicked but not sure how to fade it out when clicked on the hamburger button again. Any recommendation is highly appreciated!

**Also, the hamburger button won't appear unless the viewport is below md, please scale your viewport below md**

**HTML PAGE**

```
<div
  id="menu"
  class="h-screen flex items-center bg-black fixed top-0 w-full opacity-0 invisible duration-300 ease-out transition-opacity md:hidden"
>
  <div id="menu-items" class="lg:ml-64 ml-32 space-y-10 z-10">
    <a
      href="#"
      class="menu-item text-white lg:text-9xl md:text-7xl text-6xl block"
      >About</a
    >
    <a
      href="#"
      class="menu-item text-white lg:text-9xl md:text-7xl text-6xl block"
      >Services</a
    >
    <a
      href="#"
      class="menu-item text-white lg:text-9xl md:text-7xl text-6xl block"
      >Project</a
    >
    <a
      href="#"
      class="menu-item text-white lg:text-9xl md:text-7xl text-6xl block"
      >Contact</a
    >
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
const showMenu = document.getElementById("menu");
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".hamburger-button");
const body = document.getElementById("body");

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showMenu.classList.toggle("opacity-0");
    showMenu.classList.toggle("invisible");
    body.classList.toggle("overflow-hidden");
});
```

**LINK TO DEPLOYED SITE**
[Deployed Site](https://sunnysidechallenge.netlify.app/)

I tried creating a custom keyframes/animations on tailwindCSS to add a fadeIn and fadeOut animation to implement the fading in and out interactivity.

`

```
extend: {
      keyframes: {
        'fade-in': {
            '0%': {
                opacity: '0',
            },
            '100%': {
                opacity: '1',
            },
        },
        'fade-out': {
          '100%': {
              opacity: '1',
          },
          '0%': {
              opacity: '0',
          },
      }
      },
      animation: {
          'fade-in': 'fade-in 1s ease-out',
          'fade-out': 'fade-out 5s ease-out'
      },
```

`

However, I resulted back to just pre-built tailwindcss classes for the animations.

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to find a solution to this by:**

Implementing an if / else if statement if the menu navigation page contains a class of either "opacity-0" or "opacity-100":

```js
menuBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (showMenu.classList.contains("opacity-0")) {
        showMenu.classList.remove("opacity-0")
        showMenu.classList.add("opacity-100")
        showMenu.classList.remove("invisible")
        body.classList.add('overflow-hidden')
    } else if(showMenu.classList.contains("opacity-100")) {
        showMenu.classList.remove("opacity-100")
        showMenu.classList.add("opacity-0")
        showMenu.classList.remove("visible")
        body.classList.remove('overflow-hidden')
    }
});
```

**Regardless, my html code remains the same. If there is an another way to write this more efficiently and cleanly, feedback is appreciated!**